# C# strongly-named assembly with weakly-named reference works in one context but not another

Tags: c#, .net

### Summary

I am developing a mod for a videogame in C#. I'm also developing a utility library for mods for this videogame, which I would like to use in my mod. For what I think are good reasons*, the utility library is strongly named. This works fine when I load it in the game, but when I try to run NUnit unit tests of components of the mod that use the utility library, I get assembly load failures for assemblies referenced by the utility library. I would like some way to get the unit tests to run with the strongly-named utility library, or failing that, some other mechanism for code reuse between two mods for this game that won't run into strongly-named-assembly issues.

### What are all the assemblies involved here?

**GameEngine.dll** is an assembly in the game that I am modding. It contains types and methods central to the game that have to be used to make the mod do mod things. I don't have control over it or its behaviour. It is not strongly named.

**Mod.dll** is the central assembly for the mod I'm developing. It has references to GameEngine.dll and UtilityLibrary.dll. It is not strongly named.

**Utilities.dll** contains utility functions and types that are broadly useful across multiple mods for the game. I am developing it. It has references to GameEngine.dll. It is strongly named for reasons discussed below.

**ModUnitTests.dll** is a set of NUnit unit tests of my mod code. I am developing it. It has references to GameEngine.dll and Mod.dll.

These are all .Net Framework 3.5 for everything except ModUnitTests, which is 4.0.

### What is the precise issue?

When I load the mod in the game everything loads fine and Mod.dll can use things from Utilities.dll. Multiple mods that reference different versions of Utilities.dll load fine and use the types and methods from their version of the assembly.

But when I run unit tests that use Utilities.dll functions, the program crashes and I get the error `System.IO.FileLoadException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'GameEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. A strongly-named assembly is required. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131044)`. If Utilities.dll is not strongly named, everything works. My understanding is that I'm getting this error because the strongly-named Utilities.dll is trying to load the weakly-named GameEngine.dll and that isn't allowed. But if that's the case, why does it work in-game?

### Why is the assembly strongly named?

(Or, "Just stop hitting yourself"). If two different mods both use Utilities.dll and are loaded into the game, the second mod to load will get the types and functions from the Utilities.dll included with the first mod. If the versions are mismatched this will crash in confusing ways. The usual DLL hell issue.

I'm solely using strong-naming to get the behaviour where multiple versions of the assembly can be loaded into the same process.

I'm aware of the issues that can occur if Mod1 loads Utility1, Mod2 loads Utility2, and then Mod1 passes a type from Utility1 to Mod2. Due to the way the game is structured and mods work for the game, this shouldn't be a concern, and at any rate it's still better than the situation where Mod2 gets Utility1 to begin with.

### Help!

What I'm looking for is either a solution for getting ModUnitTests to load and run even though the strongly-named Utilities.dll is referencing the weakly-named GameEngine.dll. This appears to work when running in the game, so it's at least theoretically possible.

If that's not a thing, then I'm looking for whatever strategy C# people use when they need something resembling static linking.

Comment: Of course one obvious idea is just to keep a weakly-named version of the utility library for unit tests and use the strongly-named version for external distribution; that's error prone and kind of terrible but should work. I'm mostly worried that the setup apparently working in game is an illusion and there's an issue I'm missing.

Comment: Per your comments, strong-name verification isn't happening when the assemblies are loaded in-game (this can happen, for example, if the game engine does a custom hosting of the CLR and overrides assembly loading, which is likely). Therefore, strong-naming the utilities DLL is also not going to achieve what you want. Except when verification is disabled, weakly named assemblies cannot load strongly named ones, so no matter how you slice it you won't be able to use strong names.

Comment: I've verified that in the Mod1->Utility1 / Mod2->Utility2 case things behave like I expect in-game; Mod1 gets Utility1 behaviour; Mod2 gets Utility2 behaviour. I am actually getting what I want out of it.

Comment: So have you verified that this does *not* happen if both versions *don't* use strong names?

Comment: You should get the game distributor to distribute strongly named assemblies. No publicly available builds should come without strong names any more.

Comment: @JeroenMostert wait, no, sorry! Screwed up my test. Just verified that Mod1 -> Utility1, Mod2 -> Utility2, nothing strong named, and observed Mod1 with Utility2 behaviour. With strong naming that doesn't occur.

Comment: Interesting. Have you tried switching around the versions of the assemblies and/or the load order of the mods and/or the build times to see if you can arrange a setup where (say) Mod2 gets Utility1? It is possible the engine is partially using the CLR resolution logic to get the "right" assembly in each case, but not actually performing SN verification itself, but that's sort of a "worst of both worlds" combination.

Comment: In either case I don't really see a way around this if the engine doesn't have some sort of feature for it, short of using name changes for major versions and being compatible in minor versions. Using some sort of post-build step where you ensure the utilities DLL is always unique per mod (giving them unique names) is another option; this may load the assembly a bit more than necessary, but that doesn't seem very important. You can even drop down to copying classes/IL merging things.

Comment: Yep; the first assembly to use a Utility type loads its version and every other mod will end up getting their version. Changing names on version bumps is an idea (although with a couple obvious downsides). I did discover ilmerge as a tool and I guess that's a solution as well. The game engine is Unity which I believe uses Mono; I'm not really a C# guy but I imagine it's possible it's got slightly different loading behaviour.